# SQL: Return value based on relationship of relationship

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, azure-sql-database

Consider three tables in a SQL Server database, `STOCK`, `BINS` and `VENDORS`:

```
:: STOCK                    :: BINS               :: VENDORS
+------+-----+-------+      +-----+--------+      +----+---------+
| SKU  | BIN | COUNT |      | BIN | VENDOR |      | ID |  NAME   |
+------+-----+-------+      +-----+--------+      +----+---------+
| 1000 | A01 |     3 |      | A01 |      1 |      |  1 | Apples  |
| 2000 | A02 |     4 |      | A02 |      1 |      |  2 | Oranges |
| 1000 | B01 |     6 |      | B01 |      2 |      +----+---------+
+------+-----+-------+      +-----+--------+
```

How would I return a result set that includes all columns from the **STOCK** table, along with the vendor name from the **VENDORS** table, with a condition that I am looking for a specific sku. The vendor name would need to be determined based on the ID relationship between the BINS and VENDORS table.

The desired output:

```
+------+-----+-------+---------+
| SKU  | BIN | COUNT | VENDOR  |
+------+-----+-------+---------+
| 1000 | A01 |     3 | Apples  |
| 1000 | B01 |     6 | Oranges |
+------+-----+-------+---------+
```

I have attempted using left outer joins, as well as nested selects. Using this query for example:

```sql
SELECT [stock].*,
       (
        SELECT [vendors].[name]
        FROM [vendors], [bins]
        WHERE [vendors].[id] = [bins].[vendor]
          AND [bins].[bin] = [stock].[bin]
       ) AS [vendor]
FROM [stock]
WHERE [stock].[sku] = '1000'
```

I am getting this result (the issue being the NULL):

```
+------+-----+-------+--------+
| SKU  | BIN | COUNT | VENDOR |
+------+-----+-------+--------+
| 1000 | A01 |     3 | Apples |
| 1000 | B01 |     6 | NULL   |
+------+-----+-------+--------+
```

How would I form my query so as to achieve the desired output noted above, in the most performant manner?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Simple joins should do what you want:

```
select
    s.*,
    v.name
from stock s
inner join bins b on b.bin = s.bin
inner join vendors v on v.id = b.vendor
where s.sku = 1000
```

If there is a possibility of unknown bins or vendors, you can use `left join`s instead of `inner join`s.

Comment: After trying your suggested query and getting the same result (the null), I have realized that the issue was in fact bad data in my testing tables. The `NULL` was accurate; I had a typo between the bin name in my `STOCK` table and `BINS` table. Both the query I posted in my question, and yours, worked as soon as I corrected the sample data I was working against. Though I will use `JOINS` as you suggested, rather than the nested select.